# Ignore Pipe Symbol in Visual Studio Code Launch Arguments

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I develop an application which takes regular expression pattern as an argument. So my launch arguments look like this

```
"args": ["--exclude-fields", "id|code", ],
```

However this triggers output piping, which fails

```
bash: code: command not found
```

I have tried to escape | with various number of back slashes, but failed. Either pipe symbol triggers output piping or vanishes from argument value, so I get "idcode".

What is the correct way to include pipe symbol in argument without triggering output piping?

Comment: the `|` character is not part of the characters that will [quote the argument](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/145265#issuecomment-1103720405)

Comment: How exactly does your information help me?

Comment: That argument with the `|` needs quotes to prevent bash from interpreting it as a pipe, the `prepareCommand` function does not test if `|` is part of the argument, there is no other way of fixing it but modifying the code

Comment: it is now fixed in the Insiders Version of VSC, if you need it you can use VSC Insiders, I don't know if it was in time for the daily build, otherwise update tomorrow